# What kind of output does this sensor have?

Tags: sensor

I have encountered [this](https://studylib.net/doc/18293281/pvm-data-sheet---vigo-system-sa) sensor datasheet, and I couldn't figure out its output. Normally, a sensor should output voltage, current etc. and has calibration or sensitivity for us to translate it to what is being measured.

I couldn't figure out how this sensor is interfaced and measured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all photodiodes it is rated on A/W for IR input wavelengths and depends on aperture chip size w.
For mW of optical power it has very low sensitivity yet extremely fast response in ns.  So instead of a silicon diode of perhaps 0.5A/W it is 0.008 A/W for a 1mm aperture in one case.

The output is in uA/mW of IR power for use with a high speed transimpedance amplifier with a low source impedance from the detector.

It uses a [special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_cadmium_telluride) semiconductor for IR sensitivity

Comment: Sorry maybe it is a bit stupid question but what is the output of this sensor? Current or voltage? If I measure 0.5A it corresponds to 1W?

Comment: Do photovoltaic detectors works same way as photodiode?

Comment: Here is another example https://vigo.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/PVIA-2TE-series-datasheet-1.pdf

Comment: That one doesn’t ’ the use Hg or CD but is cooled to reduce noise and raise sensitivity greatly Current responsivity Ri(λpeak), A/W
 ≥1.3
 ≥1 yet not quite as fast

Comment: Thanks for giving some hint I need to read more about photodiodes I guess

Comment: One last question. They use TIA amplifiers with these detectors. So at the end of the day we can obtain Power versus time. I would be super glad if you can give me a hint how the time series power data is converted to wavelength spectrum?

Comment: The spectral response is given for current but the response is not converted to nm wavelengths rather from inputs of those wavelengths where risetime depends amount of reverse bias as Cjcn reduces